# Why does Victoria prohibit sex work ads from mentioning ethnicity?

Tags: australia, advertising

From [Sex worker group Vixen Collective disappointed by Victorian regulation review](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-01-29/sex-worker-group-condemns-victorian-regulation-review/7123462):

> The changes also now allow advertisements to "contain references to
>   the race, colour or ethnic origin, in addition to sexual orientation,
>   of the person offering sexual services".

Confirmation link from [Scarlet Alliance](http://www.scarletalliance.org.au/laws/vic/):

> An ad must not refer to race, colour or ethnic background of a sex
>   worker or their health status or medical testing.

(Thankfully, they're allowed to mention the sexual orientation of the worker - that the worker is female and serves male customers!)

Why does Victoria currently prohibit mention of race, colour or ethnic origin?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a political thing, that's the decision of the people in charge.

Comment: @PointlessSpike "Decisions of people in charge" is pretty much the definition of politics. I think this question is on-topic and could be answered by researching statements made by the proponents of the original legislation.

Comment: Maybe the problem is I don't know what Victoria or the Scarlet Alliance are, I assumed they were companies. If so, a decision by them is an internal decision.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Perhaps this is a discussion for the meta board, but this issue arises frequently when deal with laws and regulations. If there is a law--in this case I am assuming an act of parliament--then it is clearly a political issue. On the other hand, regulations determined by bureaucracies are less obviously so. In cases where you are dealing with cities--as this may be if it is referencing Victoria, BC--it could still be political, but I don't think there is any way that SE could ever reliably answer questions at the municipality level, with only few exceptions like NYC.

Comment: I just noticed the "Australia" tag, so apparently this is the state of "Victoria" and not a city. The meta point remains, about municipality questions, and could even be expanded to include states or provinces as I am not sure that even the most robust SE likely would include sufficient expertise about Yukon Territory, Montana, or the Northern Territory, due to the sparcity of populations there.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that from the wording, it was an attempt to further reduce discrimination. (And the change was due to that backfiring).

Comment: Is it hard to prove and is just going to allow false advertisement.